# How can i display an image from mongodb in binary with reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend

This is my model in MongoDB

```
image: {
                data: Buffer,
                contentType: String,
        }
```

And i was able to display it in the backend with EJS like this

```
<% images.map(image => { %>
                                <div>
                                        <img src="data:image/<%=image.image.contentType%>;base64,
                                                <%=image.image.data.toString('base64')%>" alt="Image" style="width:120px;height:120px">
                                </div>
                        <% }) %>
```

However when i try to display the image in the frontend with reactjs i cant, this is what i've been trying

```
   const [ images, setImages ] = useState([]);

        useEffect(() => {
                api.getImages()
                                .then(res => setImages(res.data))
                },[])

        return(
                <Fragment>
                        {images.map(image => (
                            <div key={image._id}>
                                <ul>
                                        <li><img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${image.image.data.data}`}/></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                </Fragment>
        )
};
```

Comment: In general it's a bad idea to store a binary on any database. It's simpler and cheaper to store an url reference to the object.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with this mongo document:

```
image: { url: String }
```

Then you can treat the image everywhere as a simple string, no need to decode, no binary on the database.